# How do I generate documentation which displays files inline documentation in 1 column and code in another?

Tags: documentation-generation

I've seen it before, but I can't remember which project or which documentor they used (if any).
I'm pretty sure it was a JS project, probably a Node.JS module.

Anyhow, the documentation was listed by file, and each page displayed as 2 columns, one with the inline documentation, and the other with the code.

Does anyone know which tools allow for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Annotated Documentation" is what I was trying to think of!

The tool was [docco](http://jashkenas.github.com/docco/).

The above link is docco's documentation as documented using docco.